# Print lists inside lists (3d array) without brackets, commas and quotes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I am new to python.
May I know how to print it in the following format using loop(s):

```
Table X:
    Y   Z
Y   INF INF
Z   INF INF

Table Y:
    X   Z
X   INF INF
Z   INF INF

Table Z:
    X   Y
X   INF INF
Y   INF INF
```

```
I have a 3d array currently printing out in this format:

[[['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['Y', 'INF', 'INF'], ['Z', 'INF', 'INF']], [['Y', 'X', 'Z'], ['X', 'INF', 'INF'], ['Z', 'INF', 'INF']], [['Z', 'X', 'Y'], ['X', 'INF', 'INF'], ['Y', 'INF', 'INF']]]
```

I have tried using `print("".join(map(str, list)))`, but it could only remove one outter brackets.
I also tried using

```py
for item in arr:
    print("\n".join("\t".join(map(str, item))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most confusing way, but neat:

```
x = [[['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['Y', 'INF', 'INF'], ['Z', 'INF', 'INF']], [['Y', 'X', 'Z'], ['X', 'INF', 'INF'], ['Z', 'INF', 'INF']], [['Z', 'X', 'Y'], ['X', 'INF', 'INF'], ['Y', 'INF', 'INF']]]
b = [z for w in x for y in w for z in y]
print(" ".join(b))
```

```
X Y Z Y INF INF Z INF INF Y X Z X INF INF Z INF INF Z X Y X INF INF Y INF INF
```

Comment: Hi Cory, May I know how to remove the last brackets and the quotes and commas based on your code>

Comment: You can use " ".join(b)

Answer (score 0):

*Updated!*

`DataFrame` from `pandas` helps in visualising tabulated data, make sure you read the documentation.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

for i in x:

    print("Table {}: ".format(i[0][0]))
    
    df = DataFrame(i)
    
    df.columns = [""] + i[0][1:]
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    df = df.to_string(index=False)

    print(df, "\n")
```

This should produce the required output.

Comment: Hi Jithin, thank you for your comment. It is getting close to my expected result. May I know how can I remove only the first letter in each first row and shift the last letter in each first row to the right more?

Comment: @Adrian can you update your question to specify exactly what output you hope for if this is not it?

Comment: @JonSG Thank you for the comment, I have updated the exact output I am looking for.

Comment: You can use DataFrame from pandas, it formats and outputs everything in a  cleaner way, for removing the first element, I have substituted it with a `""` and `[1:]` added to it, a slice of the original list.

Comment: @JithinJohnson Thank you for the updates and suggestions. Based on your code posted the first time, I have found another way of getting the same output.

Comment: okay, if DataFrame is used, you dont need to worry much about formatting the table,eg:  if decimals are present, pandas makes sure everything is rounded to the same number of decimal places.